# How to block keywords in https URL using squid proxy?

Tags: squid, https, url

I want to block keyword "import" in any URL, including https websites. Example:
http://www.abc.com/import/dfdsf
https://xyz.com/import/hdovh

How to create acl to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
acl ofnoimport urlpath_regex /import/
http_access deny ofnoimport
```

HTTPS might be a bit tricky, given those come through as `CONNECT` requests...

Answer (score 0):

when the site is encrypted squid can validate only the Domain but not the entire url path or keywords in the url.
To block https sites using urlpath_regex we need to setup Squid proxy using SSLbump.
It is tricky and a long process , need to carefully configure the SSL bump settings by generating certificates.. but it is possible .
I have succeeded in blocking the websites using urlpathregex over https sites...

For more detailed explaination :

Squid.conf file should have the below to achieve block websites using Keywords or Path ie..urlpath_regex

http_port 3128 ssl-bump cert=/usr/local/squid/certificate.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=4MB

acl BlockedKeywords url_regex -i "/etc/squid/.."

acl BlockedURLpath urlpath_regex -i "/etc/squid/..."

acl BlockedFIles urlpath_regex -i "/etc/squid3/...."

http_access deny BlockedKeywords

http_access deny BlockedFIles

http_access deny BlockedURLpath

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.